# How to add multiple records to a category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure the best way to ask this question, and I realize it may be out of the scope of this. I am attempting to learn rails by making simple apps that I could potentially use one day. I realize these aren't robust or secure apps, but making something I could use gives me some motivation. I've begun to get out of scope of the simple "create a blog/twitter" phase and can't find much help.

I'm attempting to make an app to book outdoor trips.

Models: Leaders, Groups, Trips, Activities, Locations and Plans

The idea is to create a "plan" to send to someone that is a publicly viewable grouping of trips. I've got everything in place to manipulate everything by the plans. They are all straightfoward models and relations.

I'm getting hung up on the best way to create a plan, and add multiple, existing trips to it. Each trip has a plan_id which can be set and the plan can simply pull that collection, but I don't know how to best (and most simply - without javascript if possible) show a list of trips and be able to select multiple and add them to a plan.

Does this make sense? I think the easiest way to begin to unravel it would be to check out the git repo: https://github.com/ryanmccrary/cabra

The https://github.com/ryanmccrary/cabra/tree/trip-plan-add branch is a half-baked attempt at one method, but I think I went about it the wrong way.

I'm not looking for the "solution" as much as the best way to do something like this and possibly some hints to get me started...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)?

Creating complex forms at the beginning of learning Rails can be a major setback, with simple form, you can just do this and trips that are already created will apear.

```
<%= simple_form_for @plan do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :trips %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

simple_form can and will make you do certain things and html markup a certain way which will make it less customizable, but if you are just trying to make simple has_many relationships, this would be the fastest way to go.

Hope it helps, I know how frustrating it can be to learn a framework and get stuck on something that seems to be trivial at first but turns out to be something that ruins the whole week.

Should try looking at some [railscast](http://railscasts.com/) episodes, there haven't been updates for a while, but there are very specific topics with source code.

Added:

If you want to associate existing trips to your plan, you would also need to make the associations between them a has many to many. You would need to create another table that would hold the association between the two together. lets call this an "agenda", sorry can't think of a good word for it. For more about associations, consult the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

models/trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many agendas
  has_many plans, through: agenda


end
```

models/plan.rb

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many agendas
  has_many trips, through: agenda

end
```

models/agenda.rb

```
class Agenda < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to plan
  belongs_to trip

end
```

Comment: Hey Saifis - this looks like the right general direction. The simple_form docs don't have anything on how to handle the output of this on the controller side. Since the form is for @plan, how to the :trips get updated to have the plan_id?

Comment: oh, sorry about that, in your case, you would need to have a has many to many association between trip and plan, since trips may belong to multiple plans and plans can have multiple trips. the plan_ids will be held in the middle table